# Cast boxed int64 to int

Tags: .net, c++-cli

In a generic class method, I have the following code:

```
System::Object^ ObjectValue;
// ...
T Value = (T)ObjectValue;
```

At one point at runtime, my class is instanciated with `T` as an `int` and `ObjectValue` contains a `System::Int64`, but the cast operation in the above code gives me a `System::InvalidCastException^`. How can I make this cast work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having will happen without generics:

```
Int64 x64 = 1;
Object^ boxed64 = x64;
int x32 = (int)boxed64;  // InvalidCastException
```

To fix cast once to unbox and then again to convert:

```
int x32 = (int)(Int64)boxed64;  // works
```

Use Convert.ChangeType to cast from an unknown boxed type:

```
int x = (int)Convert::ChangeType(obj, int::typeid);
```

For generics:

```
generic <typename T>
public ref class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar(Object^ obj)
    {
        T x = (T)Convert::ChangeType(obj, T::typeid);
    }
};
```